How to compile mesa for windows arm64 from x64 machine
Windows Build machine: x64
Windows Host machine: arm64
How to compile mesa for arm64 from the build machine ? What are the steps ?
Background:
VS 2022 is used for compilation.
I am able to compile x64 mesa using below commands:
Build LLVM for x64
Install other mesa dependencies- Win flex-bison,python3,cmake,
Command to build x64 mesa
meson setup builddir/ -Dbuildtype=release -Dgallium-drivers=zink --backend=vs
Open mesa.sln file on VS and compile - > SUCCESS
